# Ubuntu 12.04 Grub disappear + live USB don't work

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I have two partition; 1 for windows 8 and the other for ubuntu 12.04 (and of course the swap..).
It all works perfectly but then I re-installed windows 8 so the **GRUB disappeared** and it goes directly to windows 8 !
and when I tried to boot with a live USB this error appears :
"An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart"

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you did not delete ubuntu partition, you can restore grub using Boot repair disk. Download Boot repair disk ISO and burn it in a CD using imgburn. Insert the CD and restart your computer, While restarting go to bios set up and select CD drive. In Boot repair disk menu option select default repair option.